# Objective c - Issue with float division

Tags: objective-c, math, precision

I am trying to divide integer value by float, however getting wrong value. Please consider below example,

```
int a = 2;
float b = 10.0;
float result = a/b;
```

We are getting result as **0.200000003** instead of **0.2**. I want use resulted value for other calculation. 
[image]
Please let me know how to solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Use as for this

```
NSString *timeString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.1f", result];
```

Comment: This will help for displaying, won't help for calculation.